# How you introduce an input finished by newline\n, by presing enter?

Tags: python, list, input, newline

The input must be finished with newline \n, by presing enter.

Like this:

```
n= input('') > must be-> 1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1 \n must press enter
                         1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0 \n must press enter
                         1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0 \n must press enter
```

then something like this :`['1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1', '1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0', '1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0']`

then I want to split the string by ',' like this":

`a = ['1','0','1','0','1','1','0','1'], b =['1','0','1','0','1','1','0','0'],  c...`

The thing that I don't understand is how to give an input that is split by presing enter key '\n' and then run the program. If for example there was a number_of_times = how many times do you have to enter the input I would do it with an while but in this example I don't now how.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this. if you want to use the number_of_times attempt

```
number_of_times = int(input())
result = []
for i in range(number_of_times)
    line = input()
    result.append(line)

print(result)
```

or you use this you have to put an EOF at the end by pressing CTRL+D

```
import sys
result= []
for line in sys.stdin:
    result.append(line)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this simple logic, this will give you the expected output

```
lines = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if line:
        lines.append(line)
    else:
        break

list_input = '\n'.join(lines)
list_input = list_input.replace('\n', ',')
final_list = list_input.split(',')
print(repr(final_list))
```